# docker error while trying to build an image in azure devops CICD

Tags: azure, docker

Cannot build the docker image in the cicd , the path to the image is not found.

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

ARG source

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY ${source:-./obj/Docker/publish} .

#I am choising Azure pipeline agent windows-2019
```

> Step 4/4 : COPY ${source:-./obj/Docker/publish} .
>
> COPY failed: CreateFile
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\docker\tmp\docker-builder174212468\obj\Docker\publish:
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   [error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and finally solved it. I'm using the new YAML pipeline with " Docker@2" Task. The solution was to specify the "buildContext" property. I must be the same as the WorkingDir in your Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /src
```

Azure Pipeline Yaml:

```
buildContext: 'src/'
```

Full task:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
    repository: '$(imageRepository)'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'src/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: 'src/'
    tags: '$(tag)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear `COPY` can not find the file you are trying to copy during the build.

`$source` variable refers to the current directory. If $source is empty or absent, just use the default path `obj/Docker/publish`.

You can check this [issue (Is it possible to change default directory (obj/docker/publish) to copy files)](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/178) on Github or [issues-6](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/issues/6).

> When building the image it copies the content from the path specified
>   in the source argument to the current directory within the container.
>   If there is no source argument specified, the contents from the path
>   obj/Docker/publish are used.

[understanding-docker-with-visual-studio](https://www.scrum-tips.com/2017/12/27/understanding-docker-with-visual-studio-2017-part-2/)

Comment: hi thanks for you response. could you just be more specific on how i should rewrite the .dockerfile to make this work?  do i need to remove the arg source from the dockerfile?

Comment: Either pass the value to args sources or remove the source and try with `COPY obj/Docker/publish .`

Comment: i follow your suggestion but getting a different error:
- i comment out ARG source and replace COPY ${source:-./obj/Docker/publish} . by COPY obj/Docker/publish
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 12: COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined.
##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1

Comment: did you publish the app? did `obj/Docker/publish` this exists in your current directory?  check the your current working for the publish files.